# try to run java wapper "unable to bind listener to any port in the range 32000-32999"

Tags: java

I am try to run java wrapper on ubuntu this is a Server that Call Smartfoxserver  
and we are getting that error our ip table is empty and we allow all the all ip 
and ports "unable to bind listener to any port in the range 32000-32999"

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo netstat -an|less
```

and check if there is no other process listening on those ports.

Do you use SE Linux or some other security mechanism that can prevent application from binding to tcp ports and listening for incoming connections?

Or maybe your server is configure to listen at ip address that is not bound to any of your network interfaces?

Comment: I try those port are free and no way all the port form 32000-32999 are taken that is to mach <br>
I will chek what you said about the ip adress